# Запреть выход в сеть при разрыве VPN

Tags: debian, iptables, mikrotik, ipsec

Между микротиком(сервер) и Debian(клиент) настроен ipsec ikev2 туннель. Все работает, клиент выходит в сеть через микротик. При падении впн соединения клиент выходит в сеть через свой дефолтный маршрут. Как запретить средствами iptables(на клиенте) выход в интернет не через впн?

Comment: чего мудрить-то с какими-то запретами. просто не создавайте дефолтный маршрут.

Comment: Дефолтный маршрут добавляется автоматически. Если его удалить вручную, то он появляется автоматически через некоторое время.

Comment: нет, он не «появляется автоматически». его добавляет какая-то используемая вами программа. предполагаю, что, вероятно, это network-manager.

Comment: Как запретить network-manager добавлять дефолтный маршрут? Пункта "Use default route" в свойствах соединения нет.

Comment: задайте новый вопрос. здесь так принято.

Answer (score 0):

## У IPSec нет шлюзов и маршрутов!

Трафик в Вашем случае ходит так (картинка от микротика, но суть та же)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выход локального процесса в точку (K) потом цепочка OUTPUT - POSTROUTING - IPSEC - OUTPUT - POSTROUTING. Если Вы запретите выход не шифрованного трафика в фаерволе, то трафик не доберется до политик айписека.

Вариант убрать маршруты:

Поставь nm-connection-editor

В свойствах подключения по локальной сети

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тыкай по кнопке маршруты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отключи получение шлюза и других маршрутов, добавь маршрут до VPN через шлюз локальной сети.

Но тут может быть некоторая проблема, которую не проверял. Если NM не добавит маршрут по умолчанию - то трафик не пойдет и если НМ не уберет маршрут при разрыве ike - трафик пойдет куда не надо.

Решить это можно добавив виртуальный интерфейс не подключенный к сети. Рекомендую бридж (мост) с ручным адресом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда трафик без подключенного айписек будет рулиться в висящий в воздухе бридж. А когда айписек подключится он зарулится шифрованный по маршруту что прописали выше.